# Calcular boleto/parcela em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário em HTML que, após ser preenchido, os valores dos campos são enviado via método POST para um arquivo em PHP e este arquivo captura estes valores, enviando para o banco de dados MySQL.

Meu problema está no calculo de contas parceladas. Se eu fizer uma compra parcelada em 5 vezes, por exemplo, no formulário eu coloco os dados da conta, a quantidade de parcelas e o primeiro vencimento. O PHP pega o primeiro vencimento (data) e soma mais 4 parcelas seguintes. Ou seja, se a primeira parcela for dia 05/06/2017, as 4 próximas parcelas seria: 05/07, 05/08, 05/09 e 05/10/2017. O problema que ao executar o formulário, ele retorna uma página em branco e não grava nada no MySQL. As conexões estão corretas, existe retorno de erros do PHP em caso de erro de código e etc.

Segue o trecho para auxilio:

```
if($parcelado == "Sim") {

    $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER."; dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);

    for($x = 0; $x < $nParcela; $x++){

        $timestamp = strtotime("+ $nParcela month");
        //$date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp);

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO boleto(nome_boleto,data_inclusao,vencimento,valor_boleto,descricao,pago,nParcela, dataparcela) VALUES ('$boleto', '$dtpgto', '$timestamp', '$pagamento', '$descricao', '$pago', '$nParcela')";

        $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
    }

}
```

No formulário tem um campo (Parcelado?) se sim, entra nesta condição, se não entra em outra.

Segue as variáveis:

```
$dbpgto1 = $_POST['payment'];
$dtvencimento1 = $_POST['maturity'];
$boleto = $_POST['invoice'];
$dtpgto = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$dbpgto1)));
$dtvencimento = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$dtvencimento1)));
$pagamento = $_POST['value'];
$mensal = $_POST['radiosmensal'];
$descricao = $_POST['textarea'];
$nParcela = $_POST['nParcela'];  
$dataParcela = $_POST['dataparcela'];    
$pago = "Nao";
#$dataPrimeiraParcela = $_POST['dataparcela'];
#$nParcelas = $POST_['nParcela'];
$parcelado = $_POST['radiosparcelado'];
```

Por fim, se eu colocar um `echo` no final do `for`, ele retorna o que eu coloquei nele.

Comment: Dentro do `for`, tente colocar `if(!$stm) { die($conexao->errorInfo()); }` para saber se está dando algum erro.

Comment: o retorno de `strtotime` retorna um `timestamp`. Se vencimento for do tipo data você precisará converter o `timestamp` no formato correto. Utilizando `$timestamp = date ('Y-m-d',$timestamp );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você chegou a analisar o retorno de todas as variaveis do que vai para o banco de dados

Tipo você projetou 8 colunas mas só inserindo 7.

```
$date1 = explode("/", $dbpgto1);
$date2 = explode("/", $dtvencimento1);
$dtpgto = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date1[1], $date1[0], $date1[2]));
$parcela = 7;

for($i=0; $i <= $parcela; $i++){

    $nParcela = $i;

    $dtvencimento = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$i." Months",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date2[1], $date2[0], $date2[2])));

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO boleto(nome_boleto,data_inclusao,vencimento,valor_boleto,descricao,pago,nParcela, dataparcela) 
             VALUES ('$boleto', '$dtpgto', '$timestamp', '$pagamento', '$descricao', '$pago', '$nParcela', **'$dataParcela'**)";

  }
```

Comment: Verifiquei e de fato estava errado a quantidade de colunas com os Values ao banco Mysql. Fiz um teste rápido e gravou os dados, porem a data veio como 0000.00.00. Creio que seja o que @everton disse acima sobre a conversão. Irei avaliar com mais calma.

Comment: Veja se agora isso te ajuda. Se te ajudar não esqueça de marcar a resposta. :)

Comment: Foi criado as datas de forma repetidas, ou seja, se tenho 7 parcelas, a data de vencimento teve 15/06/2017 sete vezes e o que necessito é que a primeira seja 15/06/2017 e depois 15/07, 15/08, 15/09 e etc.

Comment: De uma olhada agora.

Comment: Deu certo parceiro. Obrigado :)